# in-app-purchase with issue ios7

Tags: ios7, in-app-purchase

I have created an app which was correctly running on iOS 5 and 6, and when people (and myself) upgrade to iOS7, the in-app purchase function doesn't work any more (for iPad ans iPhone version of the app): when select in app button, "Buy" is gray (inactive) and "cancel" blue (active). No way to select "buy".
Any input on this ?

Thanks for help

Tanneguy

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. From my research online i've learnt this is a `iOS7` specific bug. This post explains the problem pretty well. Even tough the post is specifically pointed at restoring purchases, it does explain the problems we are having in the sandbox server. There is no solution for it at the moment.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/897629#897629